# selecting specific lines based on second column values

Tags: awk

The following is my test.log file

```
a   1020    491 513 1   0   0   52
a   1000    491 513 1   0   0   53
sa  4011    491 513 1   0   0   0
sa  4010    491 513 1   0   0   1
d   1000    508 0   0   0   0   53
d   1020    508 0   0   0   0   52
a   1000    508 513 1   0   0   54
a   1020    508 513 1   0   0   55
sa  4011    508 1026    2   0   0   2
sa  4010    508 1026    2   0   0   3
sd  4010    508 513 1   0   0   1   QIO1
sa  4021    508 513 1   0   0   1
d   1000    525 0   0   0   0   54
d   1020    525 0   0   0   0   55
sd  4021    525 0   0   0   0   1   QIO2
a   1000    525 513 1   0   0   57
a   1020    525 513 1   0   0   56
sa  4010    525 1026    2   0   0   5
sa  4011    525 1539    3   0   0   4
sd  4011    525 1026    2   0   0   0   QIO1
sa  4021    525 513 1   0   0   0
d   1000    542 0   0   0   0   57
sd  4021    542 0   0   0   0   0   QIO2
d   1020    542 0   0   0   0   56
```

I want to extract only lines that have (first column = sa or sd) and  second columns equal to 4010 and 4011. I tried the following command.

```
cat test.log | grep "sa\|sd" | awk '{if ($2 = "4010"|| $2 ="4011")print}'
```

But it gives me wrong output.

My expected output is

```
sa  4011    491 513 1   0   0   0
sa  4010    491 513 1   0   0   1
sa  4011    508 1026    2   0   0   2
sa  4010    508 1026    2   0   0   3
sd  4010    508 513 1   0   0   1   QIO1
sa  4010    525 1026    2   0   0   5
sa  4011    525 1539    3   0   0   4
sd  4011    525 1026    2   0   0   0   QIO1
```

Can someone suggest where I am going wrong. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Be idiomatic, my friend:

```
awk '$1 ~ /^s(a|d)$/ && $2 ~ /^401[01]$/' file
#         ^^^^^^^^^           ^^^^^^^^^
#         sa or sd            4010 or 4011
```

It returns:

```
sa  4011    491 513 1   0   0   0
sa  4010    491 513 1   0   0   1
sa  4011    508 1026    2   0   0   2
sa  4010    508 1026    2   0   0   3
sd  4010    508 513 1   0   0   1   QIO1
sa  4010    525 1026    2   0   0   5
sa  4011    525 1539    3   0   0   4
sd  4011    525 1026    2   0   0   0   QIO1
```

Comment: Thanks, for the explanation

Comment: @user2532296 I hope it is clear. Note things like `awk '{if (condition) print}'` can be squeezed to a mere `awk 'condition'`.

Comment: Why `(a|d)` but `[01]`? IMHO `[ad]` would make more sense.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this entirely in grep:

```
$ grep -E '^s[ad]\s+401[01]' file
sa  4011    491 513 1   0   0   0
sa  4010    491 513 1   0   0   1
sa  4011    508 1026    2   0   0   2
sa  4010    508 1026    2   0   0   3
sd  4010    508 513 1   0   0   1   QIO1
sa  4010    525 1026    2   0   0   5
sa  4011    525 1539    3   0   0   4
sd  4011    525 1026    2   0   0   0   QIO1
```